# Implicitly converting to underlying type

Tags: c++, types, type-traits

I have some driver code which looks like this:

```
static const uint8_t PREAMBLE = 0xA0;

enum class Channel: const uint8_t {
    0 = 0x0,
    1 = 0x8
};

void foo(Channel chan) {
    bar(PREAMBLE | channel);
}
```

Where the intention is for users to be able to pass in a channel by an ID to `foo` rather than the particular mask and then my code handles forming the correct address. The problem is the compiler complains that he does not know how to XOR `Channel` and `const uint8_t`, even though the underlying types are the same. Is there some extra hint (without explicit casting) I can provide to make this work?

Comment: Your example can't compile. Please post code which is valid.

Comment: this would be one option: https://godbolt.org/z/4sMqna

Comment: I've never seen `enum class` used with a `const` backing type. What are the implications of that?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Obfuscation. For the compiler, however, it means something to ignore https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/enum#dcl.enum-2.sentence-4

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Actually that was a holdover from just making sure the `const`ness of `PREAMBLE` wasn't interfering. I haven't though of what this would actually mean but not much I would guess